# ruby dynamic dispatch with consecutive method call

Tags: ruby, dynamic-dispatch

I am encoutering a small problem while performing dynamic dispatch on some object in Ruby

I want to call a method, but I can only obtain it using multiple calls

i.e : `dynamic_string = 'my_object.other_object.this_method'`

I want to call `this_method` on `other_object` that I got from `my_object.other_object`

Here is my MCVE :

```
class A
    attr_reader :b
    def initialize
        @b = B.new
    end
end
class B
    def this
        'i want this dynamically'
    end
end

a = A.new
a.b.this # => 'i want this dynamically'
dynamic_string = 'b.this'
a.send(dynamic_string) # => error below
```

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'b.this' for #<A:0x000000025598b0 @b=#<B:0x00000002559888>>`

From what I understand the send method is trying to call the litteral method `b.this` on the `a` object.

I know that to make it work I have to make theses consecutive calls :

`a.send('b').send('this')` but I can't figure out how to make this dynamically

How can I achieve consecutive dynamic calls ? ( in this example I only need 2 calls, but I would like a more generic solution if possible, that would work for every number of calls)

Comment: Why do you have such string in the first place? Where does it come from?

Comment: in my rails app it comes from my `params[:sort_by]` , and it is the name of the column coming from the view.
For example I have the column 'header.title' so I do `@profiles.sort_by{ |a|
       params[:sort_by].inject(a) { |r, m| r.send(m) }
      }`

but I don't get why it should not be a legit question even if my string is made up ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = A.new
methods_ary = dynamic_string.split('.')
methods_ary.inject(a) { |r, m| r.send(m) }
```